Integrating level 4 progress into level 3
The level 4 is updated weekly on physical % complete and the level 3 is updated once a month with data from level 4. The level 3 is a roll up from level 4, and I can't just see how this is done. Is there anyone with some understanding?
My own effort was to getthe  weight of each activity ta level 4. This I did by dividing the original duration of an activity by the total original duration of that WBS and then multiplying it by the physical percentage complete. Am I on track?

Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements for your sample data; an English explanation of the logic that you want to implement (fully explaining any domain specific terms); YOUR attempt at a solution; the issues/errors with YOUR solution; and the expected output for your sample data. At the moment there is no detail to your question and it is probably impossible to answer.
